# How to call interface builder method press UIButton.(Navigation based )

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How to call interface builder  press UIButton.(Navigation based )

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want to select a UIButton pragramatically?

Comment: just dont go on asking questions. if some answer helps you out, acknowledge vote up and support the community. what you are doing right now can be done on Google - ask ask ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your xib file and control click and drag from the button to the File's Owner. And select the Safety_Button method when it pops up after you do the above. This wires up the action event to your button

Comment: but its not pops up after link  File's Owner to Safety Button. Why?...But my main menu  getting button image after build and run. In my coding also  [Safety_Button    addTarget:  self action: @selector(Safety_Button_Clicked:)forControlEvents:    UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; put break point its not taking action. anything wrong for created IB.

Comment: are u dragging from button to file's owner or file's owner to button? it is button to file's owner. direction matters. and also ensure you have wired your view on the whole as well by control clicking from file's owner to the view itself. pay attention to the from and to, they matter.

Comment: yes. I am dragging from button to file's owner . not on action . i think i am doing mistaken .

Answer (score 1):

try for this links
http://www.wmdeveloper.com/2010/07/create-uiview-uilabel-and-uibutton.html
may be helped you....

Comment: I build button in interface builder . if i click button .i need  to call  next method. below my code -(IBAction) Safety_Button: (id) sender;
{        
  
 
 
 if( ButtonSelected==1)
   
  { 
  
  [Safety_Button setSelected:YES];
     
  PregancyViewController *safety = [[Safety alloc] initWithNibName:@"Safety" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:safety animated:YES];
  [safety release];
  safety = nil;
   
  self.navigationItem.title=@"Safety";
 
  }

 
}